# How to get 'linked' items in an SQL query

Tags: sql, tree, oracle10g, hyperlink

I have created a 'bottom-up' tree in my SQL database tables where each element has a column for a reference to its parent.  Now I am trying to find out if there is an easy query to get all the parents of a child.

For example:

```
                          [ Parent #1 ]
                                |
               [Parent #2]             [Parent #3]
                    |                       |
         [Child # 1] [Child #2]   [Child #3] [Child #4]
```

I am giving Child #1 as the 'ID'.  Each entry has reference to it's parent, and the topmost parent is null for parent id.  So instead of in my code recursing and getting each parent, I was hoping there was a query I could do that would get Parent 1 id, parent 2 id, and child 1 id by just providing child 1 id.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Please add the appropriate tag (oracle, sql-server, mysql, ...)

Comment: Sorry...it is an Oracle 10 database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to use a hierarchical query, using the START WITH and CONNECT BY clauses.  See [this link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).

Comment: Thanks..this link helped me figure out what vettipayyan was trying to say...guess it was just a syntax issue in his/her answer that confused me.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a Hierarchical Retrieval
I guessed a query , so improvements are welcome.

`SELECT node_id

FROM tree

WHERE child_id="child_1"

START WITH id="child_1"
CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id=child_id;`

Comment: Hmm....your syntax may be confusing me a bit.  Is node_id the same as child_id?  Because the only thing i have to start with is 'child_id'.  And each of my subsequent nodes 'up' the tree have no connection to their children.  It's one way connections all the way up.  So your saying parent_id=child_id doesn't make much sense to me either.

So basically I start with id1 (which is bottom-most child), I then get the parent for id1 which is id2.  Once I have id2 I don't know who it's child is, only who it's parent is.

Comment: ya,u said it. syntax issue . Anyway u got solution ! . If u post the exact query , it's useful for others who r looking for similar problems ( Your question is of use to those who prepare for OCA )

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a [**nested set**](http://threebit.net/tutorials/nestedset/tutorial1.html) or [**adjacency model**](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql). Both have the advantage to work with any SQL database. The adjacency model works only good with a small limited number of nesting depth, while a nested set can be nested with an unlimited depth.